# Remove junk trailing xml from an inputstream

Tags: java, android, xml, xml-parsing

My free webhost appends analytics javascript to all PHP and HTML files. Which is fine, except that I want to send XML to my Android app, and it's invalidating my files.

Since XML is parsed in its entirety (and blows up) before passed along to my SAX ContentHandler, I can't just catch the exception and continue merrily along with a fleshed out object. (Which I tried, and then felt sheepish about.)

Any suggestions on a reasonably efficient strategy?

I'm about to create a class that will take my InputStream, read through it until I find the junk, break, then take what I just wrote to, convert it back into an InputStream and pass it along like nothing happened. But I'm worried that it'll be grossly inefficient, have bugs I shouldn't have to deal with (e.g. breaking on binary values such as embedded images) and hopefully unnecessary.

FWIW, this is part of an Android project, so I'm using the `android.util.Xml` class (see [source code](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Android/android-core/platform-frameworks-base/android/util/Xml.java.htm)). When I traced the exception, it took me to a *native* appendChars function that is itself being called from a network of private methods anyway, so subclassing anything seems to be unreasonably useless.

Here's the salient bit from my stacktrace:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(  678): Caused by: org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser$ParseException: At line 3, column 0: junk after document element
E/AndroidRuntime(  678):    at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser.parseFragment(ExpatParser.java:523)
E/AndroidRuntime(  678):    at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser.parseDocument(ExpatParser.java:482)
E/AndroidRuntime(  678):    at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatReader.parse(ExpatReader.java:320)
E/AndroidRuntime(  678):    at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatReader.parse(ExpatReader.java:277)
```

I guess in the end I'm asking for opinions on whether the *InputStream -> manually parse to OutputStream -> recreate InputStream -> pass along* solution is as horrible as I think it is.

Comment: ask your webhost about it (i.e. when they wont sent the js along)

Comment: It's a free webhost, they don't really do customer service unless you sign up for their full-fledged hosting. :)

Comment: and when sending hosted pics/css is the js sent along as well?

Comment: No, just for HTML and PHP pages, but only *.php documents can have dynamic content, so I'm overriding the content-type header to text/xml on those php files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm about to create a class that will take my InputStream, read
>   through it until I find the junk, break, then take what I just wrote
>   to, convert it back into an InputStream and pass it along like nothing
>   happened. But I'm worried that it'll be grossly inefficient, have bugs
>   I shouldn't have to deal with (e.g. breaking on binary values such as
>   embedded images) and hopefully unnecessary.

you could use a [FilterStream](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FilterInputStream.html) for that no need for a buffer

best thing to do is add a delimiter to the end of the XML like `--theXML ends HERE --` or a char not found in XML like a group of 16 [`\u04` chars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-transmission_character) (you then only need to check every 16th byte) to the end of the XML and read until you find it

implementation assuming `\u04` delim

```
class WebStream extends FilterInputStream {

    byte[] buff = new byte[1024];
    int offset = 0, length = 0;

    public WebStream(InputStream i) {
        super(i);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean markSupported() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int read() throws IOException {
        if (offset == length)
            readNextChunk();
        if (length == -1)
            return -1;// eof
        return buff[offset++];
    }

    @Override
    public int read(byte[] b, int off, int len) throws IOException {
        if (offset == length)
            readNextChunk();
        if (length == -1)
            return -1;// eof

        int cop = length - offset;
        if (len < cop)
            cop = len;
        System.arraycopy(buff, offset, b, off, cop);
        offset += cop;
        return cop;
    }

    private void readNextChunk() throws IOException {
        if (offset <= length) {
            System.arraycopy(buff, offset, buff, 0, length - offset);
            length -= offset;
            offset = 0;
        }
        int read = in.read(buff, length, buff.length - length);
        if (read < 0 && length <= 0) {
            length = -1;
            offset = 0;
            return;
        }

        // note that this is assuming ascii compatible
        // anything like utf16 or utf32 will break here
        for (int i = length; i < read + length; i += 16) {
            if (buff[i] == 0x04) {
                while (buff[--i] == 0x04)
                    ;// find beginning of delim block
                length = i;
                read = 0;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

note this misses throws, some error checking and needs proper debugging

Answer (score 0):

"I'm about to create a class that will take my InputStream, read through it until I find the junk, break, then take what I just wrote to, convert it back into an InputStream and pass it along like nothing happened. But I'm worried that it'll be grossly inefficient, have bugs I shouldn't have to deal with (e.g. breaking on binary values such as embedded images) and hopefully unnecessary."

That'll work. You can read into a StringBuffer and then use a ByteArrayInputStream or something similar (like StreamReader if that's applicable).

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/ByteArrayInputStream.html

The downside is that you're reading in the entire XML file into memory, for large files, it can be inefficient memory-wise.

Alternatively, you can subclass InputStream and do the filtering out via the stream. You'd probably just need to override the 3 read() methods by calling super.read() and flagging when you've gotten to the garbage at the end and return an EOF as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Free *webhost* have this issue. I'm still yet to find an alternative still in free mode.